# Non-block file systems

Tags: filesystems, block-device

I was wandering if there is a filesystem that is non-block based.

Every system I know stores or retrieves chunks of fixed size (the blocks, or clusters).

Is there a filesystem that will allow to write or read a single byte, in the context of external storage, as hard disk, flash memory etc?

I googled around, but I could't find anything conclusive.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware issue than a filesystem issue. In any case, SuperUser.com would be a better place to ask, it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Barmar My question is specific to the filesystem and, as so, to programming. I just want to know, for example, in the case  the hardware supports single-byte  (or any non-fixed size) reading/writing, if ther is a filesystem that will use such a feature.

Comment: How does it relate to programming? When you write to a file from a programming language, the way that the OS sends it to the device is totally transparent. The only programmer who needs to deal with this is the one who writes the device driver.

Comment: Filesystem for what operating system? If you're asking about Linux, try [unix.se]

Comment: IMHO, the filesystem **is** software and, therefore, related to programming. A programmer that is aware of how the filesystem deals with its IO, can write more efficient program. But I can see your point and I see no reason to continue this discussion.

Comment: Any filesystem. I just want to know an example :)

Comment: The `ls` command is also software, but if you had a question about how it works I would send you to the Unix forum.

Comment: How about `tmpfs`? It stores in virtual memory, not an external device.

Comment: Applications outside the kernel don't generally have the ability to manipulate the way the physical I/O is done or optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good reason you won't find it: none of these underlying storage technologies support byte addressing.  Flash drives and hard drives connected with SATA or SCSI are all divided into either 512-byte sectors or 4 KiB sectors.  Even if you need only one byte from a sector, you have to read the whole thing.

Part of what a filesystem does is provide an abstraction on top of these different storage technologies.